# Mask URLs with .htaccess without breaking the structure

Tags: .htaccess

is it possible to mask the url without breaking the structure?
I use LARAVEL

For example:

URL original:
`https://site.test/public/store-owner/dashboard`

URL masked
`https://site.test/public/vendedor/panel`

However, all the previous requests are not lost with the original url and the url in the address bar stays with the masked url

My .htaccess file in proyect
I have this code but the url changes in the address bar to the original one.
What I need is that the url mask does not change

```json
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^public/vendedor/panel/?$ public/store-owner/dashboard? [NC]
------------------------
FileETag none

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Redirect to non-www with https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
    
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Caching
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
#<filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
#Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
#</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(html|html|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-store"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Caching

<FilesMatch ".(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)">
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

<Files .json>
    Header unset Cache-Control
</Files>

<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#force https and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# profile redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site.test [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://site.test/stores/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Kindly do share your htaccess rules file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure this works. But just give a try

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^vendedor/panel/?$ public/store-owner/dashboard? [NC]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.
It works but nevertheless the URL changes in the address bar